# How to install a linux os in a laptop gamer?

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to install an os linux on a dell g3 but the problem I'm getting is about the network it doesn't find the right driver so the installation failed for kali .So with Kali it doesn't find the right network driver for my computer .

I have tried with ubuntu but It's seems there microfile or microservice that I don't have again so it is a failure ? I would like to understand if there is particular way to install os linux on gamers without losing the original os(windows (dual boot)) ?

I would like also explanations about the legacy mode and the uefi mode (if the choice of one or an other ) could be the reasons of my failures ?

Comment: Try to ask just one question. And provide some information about the issue. "It's seems there microfile or microservice that I don't have again so it is a failure" does not really provide enough information for most of us, so it's hard to help you. At the very least try to specify the exact model, the name of the network hardware (lspci) or an error message from Ubuntu (check the logs) will help a lot.

Comment: You clearly aren't too experienced with linux yet.  Kali may not be right for you.  Here is some [good reading why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5362/272848).

Comment: And [this is also useful](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/272848)

Answer (score 1):

UEFI - faster boot, new technology
Legacy - BIOS which you used to know.
You can dual boot or even more.
Follow this steps:

1. IN windows, go to disk management, create space where you want to install linux (it should be blank space, unpartitioned)
2. create bootable drive according to your system(UEFI/Legacy)
3. then boot, and before installing linux, try live CD. If your all hardwares are being recognised there, you are good to go.
4. Make sure you install linux in the blank unpartitioned space leaving everything as it is.

side note: for gaming you can try PopOS

Comment: Wich technology choose for the boot UEFI or Legacy ? and Why ?

Comment: windows indroduced fast boot, and for which UEFI was there, as it has more security features. If your windows is running on UEFI then you need to install your linux in UEFI mode. To check what your windows is running at, press `windows + r` and in that `msinfo32` . There in BIOS mode you can see whether your machine is running on Legacy or BIOS. You can even install 2 different OS on legacy and UEFI, but then each time you have to change from where to boot as UEFI OS will not know legacy boot and vice-versa.